# Does dapper split XML data into a list of strings?

Tags: c#, xml, orm, dapper

One of the things I've been using dapper for is to convert XML data coming from our database into strings and then deserializing it within the given object the way I need it.

I came across something today where dapper returned a list of strings containing the XML only it was split up.  Is this intended?  Should I be coding around this if I'm expecting a single string of xml to be returned?

Here's how I'm calling the proc and if you execute the proc, it returns a single result containing XML data, but dapper is returning 2 strings in the result.  If I concatenate them, then I get back what I'm expecting, but this doesn't seem like it's something I should have to concatenate.

```
var result = conn.Query<string>(procName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

EDIT: Per comment request, here is the stored procedure and example data that is being returned.  This only occurs once the XML data reaches a certain size.  Smaller batches of XML data do not cause this to happen.  The example provided here should be enough data to trigger it to happen.

**usp_ListAllGroups**

```
SELECT
   (SELECT ClassificationItemID AS '@ID', GroupCN AS '*' 
      FROM UserGroup WITH (NOEXPAND)
       FOR XML PATH('Group'), TYPE)
   FOR XML PATH('Groups');
```

**Result XML**

```
<Groups>
  <Group ID="4">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="9">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="2">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="553">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="447">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="435">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="395">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="489">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="468">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="408">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="455">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="443">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="524">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="414">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="430">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="423">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="511">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="482">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="154">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="236">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="244">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="367">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="547">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="134">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="309">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="26">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="128">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="335">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="322">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="164">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="190">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="30">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="121">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="276">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="260">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="83">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="71">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="591">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="358">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="179">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="113">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="148">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="299">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="209">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="229">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="8">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="54">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="40">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="3">SomeGroupName</Group>
  <Group ID="1">SomeGroupName</Group>
</Groups>
```

Comment: I believe it has something to do with Dapper Streaming API. Could you provide more information of the stored procedure?

Comment: @supertopi updated the answer to include more information.

Comment: What database are you using? Dapper shouldn't do that; but the database itself might.

Comment: @JonathanAllen MS SQL 2008 R2, perhaps there's a setting I could check to see if we're doing something differently than other servers?

Answer (score 0):

To read your XML from the stored procedure, you would use the SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader method which returns rows of 2,033 characters.  This is by design.  I haven't looked at the Dapper code, but from my testing, It appears that Dapper has implemented this which is very cool.

Comment: I believe that what you are suggesting is incorrect.  `SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader` returns the entire xml stream, not rows of characters.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx  I don't see anywhere in Dapper's code where they are retrieving an xml stream.  If they were then you would be correct and my issue wouldn't be happening.